# Changing the data of a node in a linked list is not altering that data for another variable referencing that same memory address

Tags: python, memory, linked-list, memory-address

I'm not sure how to title this post.

Initially I had trouble with my original linked list changing in my `main` function once I try to reverse the second half of the link list and I believe I understand it now. However, I am having trouble now understanding what is going on when manipulating the data in my linked list. I wrote down my code but near the end I wrote a separate function to explain my thought process on this and explain why I am having trouble understanding.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
    
def find_middle(head):
    slow, fast = head, head

    while fast is not None and fast.next is not None:
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next

    return slow

def reverse_second_half(head):
    middle = find_middle(head)
    second_half_reversed = reverse(middle, head)
    

    return '\nfinished'

def reverse(head, original_head):
    prev = None
    iteration = 1
    while head is not None:
        pointer = original_head

        print('\noriginal list iteration = ' + str(iteration) + '\n')
        while pointer is not None:
            print('current pointer value = ' + str(pointer.value))
            pointer = pointer.next

        iteration += 1

        next = head.next
        head.next = prev
        prev = head
        head = next
    
    return prev
    

def main():
    head = Node(1)
    head.next = Node(2)
    head.next.next = Node(3)
    head.next.next.next = Node(4)
    head.next.next.next.next = Node(5)

    print(reverse_second_half(head))

main()
```

In `main` I call `reverse_second_half` which calls `find_middle` and `reverse` functions. After I find the middle of the link list I reverse the second half of the link list starting from the middle node I found in `find_middle`.

I pass this into reverse, but I also passed in the "original list" as a second parameter. I do this because I want to see how the original list is being altered once the reversal begins execution.

I see that for the first iteration but before any reversal takes place the original linked list with all it's values gets printed, resulting in the following printed in the console.

```
original list iteration = 1

current pointer value = 1
current pointer value = 2
current pointer value = 3
current pointer value = 4
current pointer value = 5
```

for the second iteration...

```
original list iteration = 2

current pointer value = 1
current pointer value = 2
current pointer value = 3
```

and so on... (every other iteration prints out what the 2nd iteration gave as an output).

So I understand that I am manipulating not a copy of the list but the same list itself.

From my understanding we can see that the original linked list during the first iteration before any reversal takes place is

| original head |  | head |  |  | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value: 1, next: -> | value: 2, next: -> | value: 3, next: -> | value: 4, next: -> | value: 5, next: -> | None |

then step by step through the first iteration

| original head |  | head | next |  | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value: 1, next: -> | value: 2, next: -> | value: 3, next: -> | value: 4, next: -> | value: 5, next: -> | None |

| original head |  | head | None |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value: 1, next: -> | value: 2, next: -> | value: 3, next: -> | None |

here I see that the original list is altered and does not contain the second half anymore. I can see here that I do not have a separate copy of some list however we are working with the same list itself because we are just pointing variables to memory addresses. This seems weird to me though because when I do

```
next = head.next
```

during the first iteration and from the table above we see that next points to the node with value 4, however on the next line

```
head.next = prev
```

where `prev == None` should change the list to

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None
```

but if `next` points to `head.next` and `head.next` is altered to `None` how is it that

```
head = next
```

gets the list `4 -> 5`

This doesn't seem right to me I created a function to show what I'm thinking

```
def change_value_in_linked_list(head):
    middle = find_middle(head)

    middle.value = 'oops'

    while head is not None and head.next is not middle:
        head = head.next

    print(head.next.value)
    print(middle.value)

    return '\nfinished'
```

If we run the above code with the rest of the code and call this function in main without calling `reverse_second_half` just for testing purposes I see that `head.next.value` and `middle.value` contain the same data after altering `middle.value` to string `oops`. My understanding is that middle points to a memory location and when we altered it's data and tried to find the same memory location by traversing through the linked list we see that now in the original link list we find that altered data

```
1 -> 2 -> 'oops' -> 4 -> 5
```

however, if I change the function to be this instead

```
def change_value_in_linked_list(head):
    middle = find_middle(head)

    middle.value = 'oops'

    while head is not None and head.next is not middle:
        head = head.next

    head.next = None
    print(head.next)
    print(middle.value)

    return '\nfinished'
```

after changing `middle.value = 'oops'` I assume that `head.next.value` and `middle.value` is 'oops' and this is correct based on what we previously saw. However, I now added

```
head.next = None
```

I again assume that head.next points to a memory location and we are altering that data to be `None`. `middle` points to that same memory location but when printing out the data contained in `head.next` and `middle` middle still contains a valid node with a value `oops` and `head.next` is now `None`

Maybe I am missing something obvious but this is throwing me off. It's as if the argument were stating altering data in a memory location being referenced by different pointers changes the data to the altered data for every one of those pointers because those pointers are not being assigned that data but instead pointing to just the memory location, but by doing `head.next = None` and seeing that `head.next` and `middle` (two pointers pointing to the same memory location) contain different data contradicts this argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, I think your confusion lies with how variables/references are bound to objects using `=`. Maybe these graphics will help:

Initial state:
[image]

`next = head.next`
[image]

`head.next = prev`
[image]

`prev = head`
[image]

`head = next`
[image]

Your linked list has been severed.

Comment: So from what I see is that `head.next` is pointing then to a different memory location then `next` whereas changing the value doesn't change any addresses the pointers point to. I think I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's helpful! The way I think about the assignment operator `a = b` is: "bind `a` to the same object `b` is bound to".